# Determine Range in SEARCH function according to condition in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

**Summary:**

I want to verify if a certain word is in a range of cells which should be defined by a criteria.
Subsequently I would like to attribute the value of 1 or 0 depending on the existence of that word in the range.

**Explanation:**

I have a table where I have a list of countries and a list of foreign and domestic clients. An example would be this:

[image]

I then have another table where I want to attribute the number 1 or 0, depending on any entry for every country having any foreign client. If the country has any foreign entry then it should be attributed a 1, if otherwise it should be attributed a 0. In this table there is only one entry per country as follows:

[image]

In this example, the second table should be populated with a 1 for Algeria, a 0 for Angola and a 1 for Benin as only Algeria and Benin have at least one foreign client.

I have tried combining an `IF` formula with an `ISNUMBER` and a `SEARCH`. However, inside the `SEARCH` I cannot seem to define the range in which the word should be looked for depending on the country I am analyzing. Basically, what I would like Excel to do is:

1 - Check which country it is analyzing in the second table;

2 - Go to the first table and look for all entries relative to that country;

3 - Check if any of those entries has the word "foreign";

4 - Go back to the second table and attribute a 1 or a 0 for each country, depending on having found the word "foreign in any entry for that country on the first table.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: use COUNTIFS() .

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Craner said in his comment, use a COUNTIFS function.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Table1[Country],[@Country],Table1[Foreign/Domestic],"Foreign")>0,1,0)
```

This formula assumes that your first table has the name "Table1" (found on the left side of the ribbon when the table is selected and "Table Tools" is the selected tab on the ribbon).  If your table has a different name, you would change "Table1" in the formula to your table's name.

Basically, it uses structured references to test your two criteria in their respective ranges (the value in "Country" in your current table that is in the same row as the formula looked for in the column "Country" in Table1, the value "Foreign" looked for in the column "Foreign/Domestic" in Table1) to decide if it should count an item, then returns 1 if there is at least item matching both criteria or 0 if there are none.